# Using XSL to count the last number of nodes with a certain value

Tags: xslt

I have XML like this:

```
<game id="1" result="W" />
<game id="2" result="T" />
<game id="3" result="L" />
<game id="4" result="W" />
<game id="5" result="W" />
```

I'm trying to count the number of nodes from the end that have the same result as the last node.  In this case it would be 2.  I've tried for-each, but can't exit the loop after the result changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<xsl:variable name="lastValue" select="game[last()]/@result"/> 
<xsl:variable name="streak" 
              select="count(game[@result = $lastValue and 
                          not(following-sibling::game/@result != $lastValue)])" />
```